# An UU parser recognizing just the empty string input?

Tags: haskell, uu-parsinglib

I need a value of type `Parser ()` which would succeed (and return `()`) on empty (lenght 0) input, and fail in all other cases.

`pSatisfy (const False)` doesn't quite do what's required. `pEnd` doesn't even seem appropriate for this purpose.

---

`pExact 0 pAscii` might be the exact "by-definition" solution. Still doesn't seem to work:

```
ghci> runParser "<input>" (pSymbol "aaa" <|> pSymbol "bbb" <|> pExact 0 pAscii) ""
*** Exception: ambiguous parser?
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the idea of uu-parsinglib it to be more declarative than e.g. parsec, so you just have `pure ()`:

```
λ> runParser "<input>" (pSymbol "aaa" <|> pSymbol "bbb" <|> pure "") "aaa"
"aaa"
λ> runParser "<input>" (pSymbol "aaa" <|> pSymbol "bbb" <|> pure "") "bbb"
"bbb"
λ> runParser "<input>" (pSymbol "aaa" <|> pSymbol "bbb" <|> pure "") ""
""
λ> runParser "<input>" (pSymbol "aaa" <|> pSymbol "bbb" <|> pure "") "ccc"
"*** Exception: Failed parsing '<input>' :
Unexpected ''c'' at end.
```

And you need to structure your grammar in the way it doesn't need magical `EOF` symbol.